# Doing a ML predict but prices appears as in CSV

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am learning ML and running my code on prediction.  When I run the code, I find the prices in the csv is the same as the predict, what am I doing wrong?

----CODE---

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

melbourne_file_path = 'melb_data.csv'
melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path)

melbourne_data = melbourne_data.dropna(axis=0)
y = melbourne_data.Price
melbourne_features = ['Rooms', 'Price', 'Bathroom', 'Landsize', 'Lattitude', 'Longtitude']
X = melbourne_data[melbourne_features]
print(X.describe())
print(X.head())

melbourne_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
melbourne_model.fit(X, y)
print("Making predictions for the following 5 houses:")
print(X.head())
print("The predictions are")
print(melbourne_model.predict(X.head()))
```

-----OUTPUT----

```
            Rooms         Price  ...    Lattitude   Longtitude
count  6196.000000  6.196000e+03  ...  6196.000000  6196.000000
mean      2.931407  1.068828e+06  ...   -37.807904   144.990201
std       0.971079  6.751564e+05  ...     0.075850     0.099165
min       1.000000  1.310000e+05  ...   -38.164920   144.542370
25%       2.000000  6.200000e+05  ...   -37.855438   144.926198
50%       3.000000  8.800000e+05  ...   -37.802250   144.995800
75%       4.000000  1.325000e+06  ...   -37.758200   145.052700
max       8.000000  9.000000e+06  ...   -37.457090   145.526350

[8 rows x 6 columns]
   Rooms      Price  Bathroom  Landsize  Lattitude  Longtitude
1      2  1035000.0       1.0     156.0   -37.8079    144.9934
2      3  1465000.0       2.0     134.0   -37.8093    144.9944
4      4  1600000.0       1.0     120.0   -37.8072    144.9941
6      3  1876000.0       2.0     245.0   -37.8024    144.9993
7      2  1636000.0       1.0     256.0   -37.8060    144.9954
Making predictions for the following 5 houses:
   Rooms      Price  Bathroom  Landsize  Lattitude  Longtitude
1      2  1035000.0       1.0     156.0   -37.8079    144.9934
2      3  1465000.0       2.0     134.0   -37.8093    144.9944
4      4  1600000.0       1.0     120.0   -37.8072    144.9941
6      3  1876000.0       2.0     245.0   -37.8024    144.9993
7      2  1636000.0       1.0     256.0   -37.8060    144.9954
The predictions are
[1035000. 1465000. 1600000. 1876000. 1636000.]
```

Answer (score 2):

First, split your data into a train and test file.

Next, train the model using the .fit() function using your x_train and y_train datasets.

Then, run the .predict() function to make a prediction and assign the values as a list in the y_pred variable.

Finally, Make sure not to include the column that you are trying to predict in melbourne_features.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

melbourne_file_path = 'melb_data.csv'
melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path)

melbourne_data = melbourne_data.dropna(axis=0)
y = melbourne_data.Price

#Make sure not to include the column that you are trying to predict.
melbourne_features = ['Rooms', 'Bathroom', 'Landsize', 'Lattitude', 'Longtitude']
X = melbourne_data[melbourne_features]

print(X.describe())
print(X.head())

#Enter 0.50 when you wanted to have 50 percent of your data to be tested and 50 percent to be trained.
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.50)

melbourne_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)

#Alternatively, you can use RandomForestRegressor to lower down your mean absolute error compare to DecisionTreeRegressor.
#melbourne_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000)

#Fit the x_train and y_train data only. In other words, train the model. 
melbourne_model.fit(x_train, y_train)

#Finally, make a prediction.
y_pred = melbourne_model.predict(x_test)

print("Making predictions for the following 5 houses:")
print(x_test.head())

print("The predictions are")
print(pd.DataFrame({'Actual Price':y_test,
                    'Predicted Price': y_pred
                    }
                   )
      )
#The mean absolute error is a single number that you can plus or minus
#from your prediction price to get the best estimate of the actual price
#Your goal is to have as low mean absolute error as possible.
print(f'Mean Absolute Error : {mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)}')
```

Source:

1. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-decision-tree-regression-using-sklearn/
3. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error.html

Additional Reference:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaFPbb66DxQ
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSB7FtzeicA
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFaadIqWlAg
4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENvSybznF_o
5. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXoxdXMvD7c

Comment: Please focus on the suggested changes of the code and explain them, instead of just dumping a code snippet mostly similar to the OP's.

Comment: @ian I ran the code
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.5)
melbourne_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)

y_pred = melbourne_model.fit(train_X, train_y)

print("Making predictions for the following 5 houses:")
print(val_X.head())
print("The predictions are")
print(y_pred)

--output--
The predictions are
DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)

Something wrong in my code?

Comment: Sorry, I missed some parts of it. Try the edited answer above.

Comment: I ran your code, you will see the output same as head(): 

Making predictions for the following 5 houses:
       Rooms      Price  Bathroom  Landsize  Lattitude  Longtitude
6070       4   510000.0       1.0     672.0  -37.78710   144.80830
10340      3  1600000.0       2.0     598.0  -37.95357   145.02651
10737      3   450000.0       1.0     702.0  -37.66059   144.92006
1632       4  2000000.0       3.0     697.0  -37.83600   145.05600
11402      4   705000.0       2.0     815.0  -37.71757   144.81328
The predictions are
[ 510000. 1600000.  450000. ...  528000.  475000. 1755000.]

Comment: @Ian online code, pls check - https://repl.it/repls/LightheartedQuarrelsomeTriangle

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed now. You actually need to remove Price from melbourne_features. This is because Price is what you are predicting and you cannot include this from the features used to make a prediction.